# WCF set protection level for binding?

Tags: c#, wcf, security, soap

In WCF, `ProtectionLevel` is a rather important concept. The protection level controls how/if a message is encrypted and signed.

As far as I understand, the only way to set the protection level is by applying attributes to the code, and the widest scope available to set the attribute is by using the `ServiceContract` attribute on the service contract interface.

For instance, the case where you distribute service contract interface code to a third party. I.e. you hand the third party a `*.cs` file containing:

```
// inside this attribute is where you put ProtectionLevel = ...
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "some:name:space")]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract(Action = "...", ReplyAction = "...")]
    Message MyOperation(Message request);
}
```

Now imagine someone wants to use this service contract in various scenarios. In one case, the user wants to communicate using signed messages (no encryption). In the other case, the user wants both signing and encryption.

Now if I understand correctly, the user would then need TWO service contracts, one with protection level `Sign`, and one with protection level `SignAndEncrypt`.

To me this design seems a bit strange: After all, most WCF security settings are configured on the binding level (either by .config file or in code).

My questions:

- Why is it not possible to set the protection level directly on the binding? (or some other scope wider than the service contract scope)
- Or perhaps it is possible? If so, how?

Some documentation links:

- [Understanding Protection Level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347692.aspx)
- [How to: Set the ProtectionLevel Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347791.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it not possible to set the protection level directly on the
>   binding? (or some other scope wider than the service contract scope)

Specifying protection level in code is the mechanism by which the service developer can indicate that either the entire service, or certain operations on the service, require a minimum level of security. By itself, protection level does not provide any security.

The Binding provides the actual security by offering message-level encryption and/or transport level encryption, depending on the binding.

Bindings are applied *at the service contract scope* by means of binding configuration instances (defined in code or config). When a binding configuration instance has message level encryption enabled, it will consult the service contract to see if the developer has indicated any minimum level of protection required. If it finds the specified protection level then it does it's best to apply the indicated level of security. Note that this may not be possible, based on the binding selected.

> Now imagine someone wants to use this service contract in various
>   scenarios. In one case, the user wants to communicate using signed
>   messages (no encryption). In the other case, the user wants both
>   signing and encryption.
>
> Now if I understand correctly, the user would then need TWO service
>   contracts, one with protection level Sign, and one with protection
>   level SignAndEncrypt.

This is incorrect. If the binding configuration instance has message-level security enabled, and it does not find any protection level defined in the service contract, then it will by default secure all the service's communications via message encryption. If the binding config instance doesn't have message level security enabled, it will not. So you would not need two service contracts, just two binding configuration instances.

Comment: OK I think I understand. But imagine this case:

a) Message security
b) A single service contract
c) I want to call service one using signature and encryption
d) I want to call service two using signature only

How would I specify the difference between c) and d) ?

Comment: @codeape - I guess I should have read your question properly. In this instance, yes you are correct. For your specific scenario there is no way unless you have two different service contracts. However, I would hazard a guess that this is a purely contrived scenario, and not an actual one you are facing?

Comment: Yes you are right, this is me trying to understand WCF. I'm constantly tweaking binding configurations and looking at the requests and responses in fiddler. Do you have any tips for WCF blogs, books or other resources that go deep into how things actually work? IMO, the WCF documentation is too high-level.

Comment: @codeape - sounds like what you're doing is a good approach. There's a lot of myths surrounding WCF. Anything by Juval Lowy on WCF is good for a read. He was one of the main players on Indigo, which became WCF.